# MySQL Set without predefined values

Tags: mysql, sql, set

I want to have a MySQL column as a `SET` for multiple ID's, but I don't want to predefine all possible values. What I'm looking for is a MySQL datatype, which supports set-functionalities like `IN` in a MySQL query.

It's only used for numeric entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i understand correctly you need somenthing like an **ARRAY**.
There isn't something like an **ARRAY** data type in MySQL. If you are storing an Array probably a relation database isn't what you need.
You could store information in a text format using proper delimiter, for example in this way:

```
1-15-95-5-94-5
```

where **-** is the delimiter, but as I said is against ER model and of course isn't performant.

Comment: Actually I don't need an array, I need something like a list. But the thing with your example is, it is, as said, very slow and doesn't support the mentioned functionalities.

Comment: I agree, that's why I said that is slow. You won't find a data structure like the one you are looking for. MySQL is a relational database and it is designed for following normalization rules.

Comment: So to follow the er-model I would have to create a new table to combine them, right? So actually just two columns and both defined as key?

Comment: Yes you should use another table where you store the ID of the first table and the number you want to save, one row for each number of your list.